# What could be an alternate of iteritems() [from python] in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, dictionary

How can I perform an action similar to python's `.iteritems()` in javascript?

Comment: Define what particular aspect of `.iteritems()` you want to emulate...

Answer (score 3):

In ECMAScript 2015, [`Map` objects have `entries()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries). That is the closest, compared to Python's `iteritems`.

```js
var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set("0", "foo");
myMap.set(1, "bar");
myMap.set({}, "baz");

var mapIter = myMap.entries();

console.log(mapIter.next().value); // ["0", "foo"]
console.log(mapIter.next().value); // [1, "bar"]
console.log(mapIter.next().value); // [Object, "baz"]
```

Or use it with `for..of` loop, like this

```
for (let items of myMap.entries()) {
  console.log(items);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will just try and understand the whole concept.

Comment: can you please look into my new question regarding itemitems(). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34649845/convert-the-python-code-to-get-the-json-as-the-output

Comment: function iteritems(collection) { return Object.keys(collection).map((key) => [key, collection[key]])